# Read stdin for user input when a file is already redirected to stdin

Tags: bash

So I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
while read line; do
    read userInput
    echo "$line $userInput"
done < file.txt
```

So say file.txt has:

```
Hello?
Goodbye!
```

Running the program would create:

```
Hello?
James
Hello? James
Goodbye!
Farewell
Goodbye! Farewell
```

The issue (naturally) becomes that the userinput read reads from stdin which in our case is file.txt. Is there a way to change where it's reading from temporarily to the terminal in order to grab user input?

Note: The file I am working with is 200,000 lines long. and each line is about 500 chars long. So keep that in mind if needed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using redirection, you can open `file.txt` to a file descriptor (for example 3) and use `read -u 3` to read from the file instead of from `stdin`:

```
exec 3<file.txt
while read -u 3 line; do
    echo $line
    read userInput
    echo "$line $userInput"
done
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Jaypal Singh, this can be written as:

```
while read line <&3; do
    echo $line
    read userInput
    echo "$line $userInput"
done 3<file.txt
```

The advantage of this version is that it's POSIX compliant (the `-u` option for `read` does not appear in POSIX shells such as `/bin/sh`).

Comment: @jcollado Though I have one small suggestion, instead of doing `exec` on a separate line you can have it written like this - `while read line <&3; do echo $line; read userInput; echo "$line $userInput"; done 3<file.txt` :)

Comment: Ok, I see, I cannot delete an accepted answer :/

Comment: @miku Since you permitted it I switched it over.

Comment: @JaypalSingh I've updated my answer. Thanks a lot for your suggestion because the code now works also in `sh`.