# Pause loop and wait for user input

Tags: bash, shell

I am facing an issue as not able to pause inside a function and wait user confirmation to continue or exit the script, the background is I am writing a verification function which verify against an input file and I want it pause when encounter a certain value from input, ideally it able to temporary suspend the function and provide user a menu including `Continue` or `Exit`, only after user select the function will resume the execution or the script terminate.

Create an example to test, some idea get from [Press space to continue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134437/press-space-to-continue) and [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script?rq=1), as my test, it not work by just ignore the `read` command line which suppose to pause function and wait user input.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
function pause(){
 read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n'
}

function wait_user_confirm() {
  echo "When encounter number 2 ask user to confirm continue"
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" -eq 2 ]]; then
      pause # Not pause the function till user input and ignored by script
    else
      echo "Skip"
    fi
  done < "input.txt"
}

wait_user_confirm
```

input.txt

```
1
2
3
```

Test result:

```
When encounter number 2 ask user to confirm continue
skip
skip
```

I test that `read` command individually (**not inside a function**, directly as a command line only), it works properly, the issue not because of `read` command, its because it not able to pause inside a function of shell script. How can I properly pause the function of shell script and wait for user input by providing a select menu ? Appreciate all the help, thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Read input inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883363/read-input-in-bash-inside-a-while-loop), or [Read stdin for user input when a file is already redirected to stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886683/read-stdin-for-user-input-when-a-file-is-already-redirected-to-stdin)

Comment: Hi, oguz ismail, let me check the link, thank you for providing idea, will confirm weather it works

Comment: Hi, oguz ismail, the given 2 links really helpful, resolve my doubt by redirecting the while loop read from regular stdin to other fd, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that both of your `read` calls work on the same input filehandle (`input.txt`, which you redirected), while you intended the `pause` function to read from the original standard input handle instead.

To solve this, you could for example use a different fd (e.g. 4) for the `input.txt` file, like so:

```sh
# (...)

function wait_user_confirm() {
  while IFS= read -ru4 line; do

    # (...)

  done 4< "input.txt"
}
```

(note the `-u4` passed to read and the redirection to fd 4 at the end)

Comment: Hi, Chris Smeele, thank you for providing the idea, will check and confirm back if this work

Comment: Nice, thank you Chris Smeele, the `-u4` redirection explicitly resolve the issue, not only in this small demo example, also merged and test in original function, works properly !